# How could I turn off the terminal line number while keep the editor line number in vimrc

Tags: vimrc, terminal, line-numbers

I want to show line number in the editor, thus I use `set nu` in my `vimrc`. But when I open the embedded terminal with `:ter`, there are also line numbers there which I feel not comfortable. How could I switch off the line numbers in the terminal while still keep the line numbers of the editor window ?

Comment: doesn't this only happen in terminal normal mode? e.g. while the job is running, no line numbers are shown. In any case, have your tried a `TerminalOpen` autocommand, e.g. `:au TerminalOpen * :set nonu`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks the helpful comment provided by Christian Brabandt. The answer is to add a line in the `.vimrc`:

```
autocmd TerminalOpen * set nonu
```

Comment: With this command the terminal window will have no line numbers, but when you open a new edit buffer that buffer also has no line numbers. Better to use `setlocal` like ```autocmd TerminalOpen * setlocal nonu```

Comment: Note that neovim doesn't declare the TerminalOpen group, and instead declares TermOpen. So for neovim you can use `autocmd TermOpen * setlocal nonu`